# Use Toad Data Point to graphicaly choose values for IN operator in where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, toad

I'm trying to add static values into my `IN` operator.

Such as

```
Where Customers.Name in ('Jack', 'Jill')
```

But I'm only able to add one value for an `=` operator

Such as

```
Where Customers.Name = 'Jack'
```

I am able to type them into the Formula window

But, Is there a way to graphically choose values for the IN operator, rather than have to type them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Click the ellipsis button on the Where line of the field you want to query on.  Then pick In (instead of equals) and check the boxes in the drop down for the items you want.

(src: http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-data-point/f/36/t/29888)